# Xcode 8.1 IOS10.1 CoreData delete does not really delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am experiencing a very weird behaviour with iOS core data, I am downloading items from a web service and storing it locally using core data, I have one UTTableViewController that shows what is stored in the local entity, the same tableController also allows for delete action on selected items.
I also have a constraint on the attribute "itemId" to avoid duplicates and I use the default behaviour to throw an error if itemId is a duplicate

The problem is as follows

When I download the items from the webservice the first time it works exactly as intended.

If I try and reload the data the constraint correctly shows me errors that there are conflicts.

I then go into the UITableViewController and I delete one of the items, this works as expected the ViewCOntroller shows the remaining items.

Now I reload the items from the web service, and now it cannot add back the one that was deleted, the constraint tells me there is conflict.

It is as if the item is not really deleted and still hangs around in the background but not visible.

Debugs show me that all looks good

Can someone help me explain why I am getting the constraint error when I reload the same itemId that I deleted.

This is the download method

```
+ (void)fetchTillData:(int)tillId; {

if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
    NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillData:tillId = %d", tillId);
}

NSString *finalURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://foo.bar.com:5443/api/till/tilldata/%d?StartAtRow=0&TakeNoOfRows=10",tillId];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalURL]
                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                 if (error != nil) {
                                     if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
                                         NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillData:Transport error %@", error);
                                     }
                                 } else {
                                     NSHTTPURLResponse *responseHTTP;
                                     responseHTTP = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

                                     if(responseHTTP.statusCode != 200) {
                                         if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
                                             NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillData:Server Error %d", (int) responseHTTP.statusCode);
                                         }
                                     } else {
                                         NSArray *tillBasicDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                       options:0
                                                                                                         error:NULL];
                                         if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
                                             NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillData:tillBasicDataArray count = %lu", (unsigned long)[tillBasicDataArray count]);
                                             NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillData:tillBasicDataArray looks like %@",tillBasicDataArray);
                                         }

                                         NSDictionary *tillBasicDataDict = Nil;

                                         //Loop through the array and for each dictionary insert into local DB
                                         for (id element in tillBasicDataArray){
                                             tillBasicDataDict = element;

                                             NSString *itemId = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"itemId"];
                                             NSString *companyId = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"companyId"];
                                             NSString *languageId = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"languageCode"];
                                             NSString *colorCode = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"colorCode"];
                                             NSString *discountable = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"discountable"];
                                             NSString *exchangeable = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"exchangeable"];
                                             NSString *noos14 = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"noos14"];
                                             NSString *sizeCode = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"sizeCode"];
                                             NSString *taxGroup = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"taxGroupId"];
                                             NSString *taxRegion = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"taxRegion"];
                                             NSString *tradeItemDesc = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"tradeItemDesc"];
                                             NSString *withTax = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"withTax"];
                                             NSString *status = [tillBasicDataDict objectForKey:@"status"];

                                             // Use Core Data FMD
                                             AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

                                             //AppDelegate *appDelegate =
                                             //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

                                             NSManagedObjectContext *context =
                                             appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;
                                             NSManagedObject *newPimItem = Nil;
                                             newPimItem = [NSEntityDescription
                                                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TillData"
                                                            inManagedObjectContext:context];

                                             [newPimItem setValue:itemId forKey:@"itemId"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:companyId forKey:@"companyId"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:languageId forKey:@"languageCode"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:colorCode forKey:@"colorCode"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:discountable forKey:@"discountable"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:exchangeable forKey:@"exchangeable"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:noos14 forKey:@"noos14"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:sizeCode forKey:@"sizeCode"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[taxGroup intValue]] forKey:@"taxGroup"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:taxRegion forKey:@"taxRegion"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:tradeItemDesc forKey:@"tradeItemDesc"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[withTax intValue]] forKey:@"withTax"];
                                             [newPimItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[status intValue]] forKey:@"status"];

                                             NSError *error = Nil;
                                             [context save:&error];

                                             if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
                                                 NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillData:ItemId in loop = %@", itemId);
                                                 NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillData:newPimItem = %@", newPimItem);
                                                 NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchTillData:CoreData error = %@", error);
                                             }

                                             if(error != nil) {
                                                 // Do something here
                                             } else {
                                                 NSUserDefaults *tillUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                                                 [tillUserDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"hasTillData"];
                                                 [tillUserDefaults synchronize];
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             }] resume];
}
```

The debugs show me that I don't have any NIL/NULL values anywhere

The debugs also shows me that each variable is holding the expected value

Below is the JSON array from the webservice using NSLog, all values are correct

```
WebServices:fetchTillData:tillBasicDataArray looks like (
    {
    colorCode = 95;
    companyId = "BE_HM";
    discountable = 1;
    exchangeable = 1;
    itemId = 101064025138010;
    languageCode = eng;
    noos14 = "09258384374953,09258387354952";
    sizeCode = "163-010";
    status = 1;
    taxGroupId = 1;
    taxRegion = BE;
    tradeItemDesc = "Jersey basic";
    withTax = 1;
},
    {
    colorCode = 95;
    companyId = "BE_HM";
    discountable = 1;
    exchangeable = 1;
    itemId = 101064025138011;
    languageCode = eng;
    noos14 = "09258384394951,09258387434951";
    sizeCode = "163-011";
    status = 1;
    taxGroupId = 1;
    taxRegion = BE;
    tradeItemDesc = "Jersey basic";
    withTax = 1;
},
    {
    colorCode = 95;
    companyId = "BE_HM";
    discountable = 1;
    exchangeable = 1;
    itemId = 101064025138012;
    languageCode = eng;
    noos14 = "09258385254957,09258389874953";
    sizeCode = "163-012";
    status = 1;
    taxGroupId = 1;
    taxRegion = BE;
    tradeItemDesc = "Jersey basic";
    withTax = 1;
}
)
```

but I still receive this error even after I have deleted all the entries and the tableViewController shows that my DB is empty

```
    2016-11-23 15:07:36.714 NWMobileTill[674:9231] WebServices:fetchTillData:ItemId in loop = 101064025138010
2016-11-23 15:07:36.715 NWMobileTill[674:9231] WebServices:fetchTillData:newPimItem = <TillData: 0x6000002ce9a0> (entity: TillData; id: 0x600000624620 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D15> ; data: {
    colorCode = 95;
    companyId = "BE_HM";
    discountable = 1;
    exchangeable = 1;
    itemId = 101064025138010;
    languageCode = eng;
    noos14 = "09258384374953,09258387354952";
    sizeCode = "163-010";
    status = 1;
    taxGroup = 1;
    taxRegion = BE;
    tradeItemDesc = "Jersey basic";
    withTax = 1;
})
2016-11-23 15:07:36.717 NWMobileTill[674:9231] WebServices:fetchTillData:CoreData error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133021 "(null)" UserInfo={conflictList=(
    "NSConstraintConflict (0x60000086dcc0) for constraint (\n    itemId\n): database: (null), conflictedObjects: (\n    \"<TillData: 0x6000000de4c0> (entity: TillData; id: 0x600000435500 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D7> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138012;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258385254957,09258389874953\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-012\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\",\n    \"<TillData: 0x6000002ce3f0> (entity: TillData; id: 0x60000023bda0 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D13> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138012;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258385254957,09258389874953\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-012\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\",\n    \"<TillData: 0x6080002cfc00> (entity: TillData; id: 0x60800022f920 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D4> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138012;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258385254957,09258389874953\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-012\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\"\n)",
    "NSConstraintConflict (0x60000067fd40) for constraint (\n    itemId\n): database: (null), conflictedObjects: (\n    \"<TillData: 0x6080002d0760> (entity: TillData; id: 0x608000233320 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D6> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138011;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258384394951,09258387434951\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-011\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\",\n    \"<TillData: 0x6080002cfb20> (entity: TillData; id: 0x60800022f9e0 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D3> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138011;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258384394951,09258387434951\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-011\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\",\n    \"<TillData: 0x6080002d3be0> (entity: TillData; id: 0x608000221ea0 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D12> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138011;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258384394951,09258387434951\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-011\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\"\n)",
    "NSConstraintConflict (0x60000067fc00) for constraint (\n    itemId\n): database: (null), conflictedObjects: (\n    \"<TillData: 0x6080002cecb0> (entity: TillData; id: 0x6080002218e0 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D5> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138010;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258384374953,09258387354952\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-010\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\",\n    \"<TillData: 0x6080002cf2d0> (entity: TillData; id: 0xd000000000180002 <x-coredata://6A608EA5-F8C8-4272-8C10-8621BB730066/TillData/p6> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138010;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258384374953,09258387354952\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-010\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\",\n    \"<TillData: 0x6000002ce9a0> (entity: TillData; id: 0x600000624620 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D15> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138010;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258384374953,09258387354952\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-010\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\",\n    \"<TillData: 0x6080002d1e20> (entity: TillData; id: 0x608000229160 <x-coredata:///TillData/t7807C999-528C-4616-A012-592A3D77D28D11> ; data: {\\n    colorCode = 95;\\n    companyId = \\\"BE_HM\\\";\\n    discountable = 1;\\n    exchangeable = 1;\\n    itemId = 101064025138010;\\n    languageCode = eng;\\n    noos14 = \\\"09258384374953,09258387354952\\\";\\n    sizeCode = \\\"163-010\\\";\\n    status = 1;\\n    taxGroup = 1;\\n    taxRegion = BE;\\n    tradeItemDesc = \\\"Jersey basic\\\";\\n    withTax = 1;\\n})\"\n)"
)}
```

The delete code looks as below and it shows no error when delete is done

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.pimItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
            }
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [self.pimItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    }
```

Any help would be very helpful

------ EDIT ------

After I delete from the tableView and close the app, restart the app I am able to load the data again as expected, but not a long as I remain in the app navigating to different parts of the app and then back I cannot do it even though debugs tells that when I enter the tableView its empty but when I try load data I get the error

Debugs showing that the persistent store is empty

```
2016-11-23 16:09:04.106 NWMobileTill[1554:32365] pimItemsArray holds (
)
2016-11-23 16:09:04.106 NWMobileTill[1554:32365] fetchReuestError holds (null)
```

as you can see the array that backs the tableview is empty and the fetch request has NULL so the persistent store is empty, if its empty why can I not reload the data?

This is the code that populates the tableView

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSError *error = nil;

// Fetch the devices from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"TillData"];
self.pimItems = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
    NSLog(@"pimItemsArray holds %@", self.pimItems);
    NSLog(@"fetchReuestError holds %@", error);
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean, I read the link and I am doing the same thing just not looping over the NSManagedObject since I only worry about one row in the table. so I call deleteObject and then save the context which should delete the object from the persistent store

Comment: If I do the delete in the table, quit the app, start the app, then it works, but if I remain in the app and go back to the main menu and back into the admin menu to load data it does not work.

Comment: I cannot read them, they are not there as far as I can see, the following debug confirms that when I load the Tableview and reads from the Persistent store its empty

Comment: Are `appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext` and `self.persistentContainer.viewContext` pointing to the same `context`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had not used the appDelegate in all places consistently

The following line from WebServices class needed to be in all places

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

Thanks Vinodh and Flexicoder for pointing that out